# How to enable HTTPS on EC2 Tomcat webapp with Load Balancer

Tags: ssl, tomcat, amazon-ec2, https, amazon-elb

To enable HTTPS on my website deployed on an Apache Tomcat on an EC2 AWS instance I created an application load balancer and created an SSL certificate with the certificate manager like it is presented in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QA4X8ntcNBQ
After creating the load balancer it is said in this tutorial that you have to make a few configurations on the Apache Server. But in my case I use an Apache Tomcat and wonder which configurations I should do here to get https to work. Hope you can help me with that.

Answer (score -1):

You can skip this part you can use the free Cloudflare with your domain and point to your ec2 directly to get an SSL connection

you don't need ALB just for an SSL (no configuration needed)

Still, if you want to go this route you can follow these steps

https://geekflare.com/tomcat-ssl-guide/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Well I tried to use Cloudflare but there comes an error when I try to protect the url ec2-[...].eu-central-1.amazonaws.com. Could imagine that this is because I'm not the owner of amazonaws.com? Because of that I wanted to implement the application load balancer. Is it possible to implement the ACM certificate into the steps of your geekflare url? Sorry for asking silly questions but I'm very new to that deployment stuff and am a little confused by all these possibilities. Important to know: I need a ca certificate not a self-signed one.

Comment: You can use an elastic IP to point to Cloudflare rather than the DNS name (eu-central-1) and it will work

Comment: When I exchange the eu-central-1 with the Elastic IP the response is the following error: 'Please ensure you are providing the root domain and not any subdomains (e.g., example.com, not subdomain.example.com)'